# How to call nested functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pointers on how to fix my code? This code asks for user input on the number of tickets sold, and returns the income generated using functions

I am not sure about what how to call each function

```
secA = 20
secB = 15
secC = 10

def main():
    print("The income generated from all sections is: ", total)
def getTickets(A,B,C):
    sectionA = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section A: ")
    sectionB = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section B: ")
    sectionC = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section C: ")

    def ticketsValid():
        while sectionA > 300:
                print("ERROR: Section A has a limit of 300 seats")
        while sectionB > 500:
                print("ERROR: Section B has a limit of 500 seats")
        while sectionC > 200:
                print("ERROR: Section C has a limit of 200 seats")

    def calcIncome():
        total = secA * sectionA + secB * sectionB + secC * sectionC
        print("The income generated is $", format(total, '.2f'))   
main()
```

Comment: If you don't know how to deal with nested functions, then why are you nesting functions? What problem do you hope to solve by nesting the functions?

Comment: @karl I don't believe that that was the original name. I think that it was changed as that was *thought* to have been the purpose of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question: to call all of the functions you need to put the names of your functions into the `main()` function. But, you had several other errors so I have decided to walk you through the program, step-by-step.

First, we set the prices:

```
secA = 20
secB = 15
secC = 10
```

Here is the first function, `getTickets()`

```
def getTickets():

    global A
    A = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section A: "))

    global B
    B =int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section B: "))

    global C
    C =int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section C: "))
```

Notice the word `global` before I use the variable. This tells the computer that this variable can be used everywhere. Next, notice the double parentheses - since both `int()` and `input()` are functions, so we need to show that by doing that.

I fixed your code for the `ticketsValid()` function. Usually, it isn't a good idea to nest functions, so this is at the same indentation level as the above code.

```
def ticketsValid(A,B,C):
    while A > 300 or A < 0:
        print("ERROR: Section A has a limit of 300 seats\n")
        A = int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section A: "))
    while B > 500 or B < 0:
        print("ERROR: Section B has a limit of 500 seats")
        B =int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section B: "))
    while C > 200 or C < 0:
        print("ERROR: Section C has a limit of 200 seats")
        C =int(input("Please enter the number of tickets sold in section C: "))
```

This gets the variables from above, and checks to see if they are valid. Notice that I added a check for negative numbers - you can't sell negative tickets.

Then we come to `calcIncome(A,B,C)`:

```
def calcIncome(A, B, C):
    total = A * secA + B * secB + C * secC
    print ("The income generated is $%d" % (total))
```

First, we multiply the sections by the set prices to calculate the total. Then, we print it.

Lastly, we need to call the functions. I used your idea for a *main()* function, which uses the other functions. It looks like this.

```
def main():
    getTickets()
    ticketsValid(A,B,C)
    calcIncome(A, B, C)
```

It simply calls the other functions, in the correct order, when run.

Lastly, we call the `main()` function by typing:

```
main()
```

I hope that this answered your question. If not, feel free to comment. If so, please check the green check mark next to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand the errors I made on this problem. However, my teacher gave us certain parameters on this problem. She does want us to include the input function "getTickets." as well as a Boolean indicating whether the passed tickets sold for the given section is in the valid range. If the number of tickets exceeds the limit, I suppose she wants the program to ask again for a valid number. If you could give me pointers on how to create this program with those parameters that would be great. This is my first programming class I have ever taken.

Comment: @KevinChoi Ok - thanks for the clarification. I will update my code with the proper stuff (for lack of a better word.) Also, I recommend that you buy [Python for the Absolute Beginner](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/python-programming-for-the-absolute-beginner-michael-dawson/1100212232?cm_mmc=googlepla-_-textbook_instock_26to75_pt106-_-q000000633-_-9781435455009&cm_mmca2=pla&ean=9781435455009&isbn=9781435455009&r=1) which will help you get ahead in class. It's an awesome book.

Comment: @KevinChoi Also, do you have to nest the functions? That is *way* more complex. Lastly, is it ok to merge the `getTickets()` and `ticketsValid(A,B,C)` functions?

Comment: Nesting functions is not required, though I think she does want to have those three functions on their own. She wants the input function "getTickets" and validation function "ticketsValid" on their own.

Comment: @KevinChoi I fixed my answer. Hopefully this is satisfactory. If you need any help, go to chat and say .@xxmbabanexx <insert myMessage/Link to question> I will try to help you as quickly as possible.

Comment: @KevinChoi Not to be pushy, but if this was helpful please give me the green checkmark.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the problem much better now. I did run the program but there are still some traceback issues.

Comment: @kevin What were the issues? I was porting this from 2 to 3, and I didn't test that. Could you tell me what the issues were?

Comment: It says in line 34, in <module> main(), as well as line 31, in main ticketsValid(A,B,C). Also, it says NameError: global name 'A' is not defined.

Comment: Actually I have just fixed my code! I added the getTickets() function to the main module. Thank you so much for helping me with this problem! I have checked your response green.

Comment: @KevinChoi Oh - I added that in my code but forgot to add it here. So sorry! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to know how to use a nested function:

```
def f():
    def g(): #this defines a function but does not call it
        print "run g"
    g() # this calls g.
```

Typically, nested functions should not be available outside its parent function. Since the point of using a nested function is that the function only helps its parent function to do things. If you want it outside, consider define it as a new function.

In your case, you need to consider how to break up your code into parts.
If I were you, I would use getTickets() to get tickets.
The ticketsValid is fine, though I would let it return a boolean.
calcIncome would return the total income.
So the general design is like:

```
def main():
    (A, B, C) = getTickets()
    if(ticketsValid(A, B, C)):
        income = calcIncome(A, B, C)
        print("The income generated from all sections is: ", income)

def getTickets():......
def ticketsValid(A, B, C):......
def calcIncome(A, B, C):......
```

I think this would be a better design.